# Array of buttons, some with dropdown, but the dropdown opens on all buttons

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of buttons in an Angular application where I need to display them in a top bar with *ngFor. But only four of them have a dropdown, but when I click on one of those that has a dropdown, the same submenu appears under all the buttons. I believe it could be something very simple that I haven't seen in a general context of Array logic, but I've already tried to pass the loop just inside the button itself, but in this case, each dropdown appears completely shifted to the left of the entire group of buttons. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Here's code:

Component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuButtons" class="d-inline-block">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button [ngStyle]="!showLabel && { 'color': '#495057' }" type="button" class="btn" (click)="catch(item.icon)">
        <i class="material-icons-outlined">{{item.icon}}</i>
        <span>{{item.label | translate}}</span>
    </button>
    <div [ngClass]="Class" (mouseleave)="closeLabel()" class="dropdown-menu">
        <kt-info-label ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="chosenLabel === 'info'"></kt-info-label>
        <kt-mass-actions-label ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="chosenLabel === 'rocket_launch'"></kt-mass-actions-label>
        <kt-layout-label ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="chosenLabel === 'edit'"></kt-layout-label>
        <kt-save-label ngbDropdownItem *ngIf="chosenLabel === 'save'"></kt-save-label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    /* Array com ícones, textos Label */
public menuButtons: Array<any> = [
    {icon: 'arrow_back', label: 'MUB.T115'},
    {icon: 'info', label: 'MUB.T658'},
    {icon: 'file_download', label: 'MUB.T593'},
    {icon: 'rocket_launch', label: 'MUB.T2114'},
    {icon: 'dashboard_customize', label: 'MUB.T2154'},
    {icon: 'edit', label: 'MUB.T173'},
    {icon: 'add_circle_outline', label: 'MUB.T2210'},
    {icon: 'delete', label: 'MUB.T80'},
    {icon: 'save', label: 'MUB.T62'}
]


showLabel: boolean = false

public chosenLabel: string = ""

public Class: string= 'open-'

catch(icon: string) {
    if (this.chosenLabel != icon || this.showLabel) {
        this.closeLabel()
    }
    if(!this.showLabel) {
        this.chosenLabel = icon
        this.Class = `${this.Class}${icon}`
        this.showLabel = true
    } else {
        this.closeLabel()
    }
    if (this.chosenLabel === 'arrow_back') {
        this.back()
    }
}

closeLabel() {
    this.showLabel = false
    this.Class = 'open-'
}

back(): void {
    this.location.back()
}
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz. I don't know what these directives and components are doing.

Comment: side note: the property name "Class" (and you probably used the upper "C" just because "class" is a reserved keyword) for a CSS class is not a good idea at all. It should be more specific / descriptive to what it's styling.